# Which is the best approach to avoid cross site scripting in WordPress with JS inline?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is my doubt, having to use JS inline inside a php file I need to pass a dynamic variable to this code:
`'<script type = "text / javascript">document.location.href = "’. $ url.' ";</script>';`

Which possible solution is preferable to avoid cross site scripting?

Solution 1:
`'<script type = "text / javascript">document.location.href =' .esc_js ($ url). ');</script>';`

Solution2:
`'<script type = "text / javascript">document.location.href = encodeURI ("'. esc_js ($ url). '");</script>';`

Solution3:
None of the two

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Where does `$url` come from? User input you've received previously? Something else?

Comment: No, the variable do not come from user

Comment: So where does it come from?

Comment: Then there's no XSS issue in that code. Which is to say: If you trust the source of the content of `$url` (it didn't come from a user) and you know it doesn't contain malicious content, just appending it to your code doesn't raise a new issue.

Comment: Let me explain: the user sends a form and is redirected to another page at the end, based on the URL that I change according to the needs. This variable is chosen by me